# Fitbit Data Export - Creating a data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, fitbit

I plan to create a Fitbit data warehouse for educational purposes, and there doesn't seem to be any material online for Fitbit data specifically.

A few issues faced:

1. You can only export 1 month of data (max) at a time from the Fitbit website. My plan would be to drop a month's worth of data at a time into a folder, and have these files read seperately.
2. You can either export the data through CSV or .XLS. The issue with XLS is that each day in the month will create a seperate sheet for food logs, which will then need to be merged in a staging table. The issue with CSV would be that there is one sheet per file, with all of the data in there: [CSV Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P87M1.png)

I would then use SSIS to load the data into a SQL Server database for reporting purposes.

Which would the more suited approach be, to export the data using .XLS format or CSV?

Edit: How would it be possible to load a CSV file into SSIS with such a format?

The CSV layout would be as such:

Body,,,,,,,,,
Date,Weight,BMI,Fat,,,,,,
01/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
02/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
03/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
04/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
05/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
06/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
07/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
08/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
09/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
10/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
11/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
12/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
13/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
14/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
15/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
16/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
17/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
18/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
19/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
20/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
21/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
22/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
23/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
24/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
25/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
26/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
27/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
28/06/2018,71.5,23.29,15,,,,,,
29/06/2018,72.8,23.72,15,,,,,,
30/06/2018,72.95,23.77,15,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,

Foods,,,,,,,,,
Date,Calories In,,,,,,,,
01/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
02/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
03/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
04/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
05/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
06/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
07/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
08/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
09/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
10/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
11/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
12/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
13/06/2018,100,,,,,,,,
14/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
15/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
16/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
17/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
18/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
19/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
20/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
21/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
22/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
23/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
24/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
25/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
26/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,
27/06/2018,"1,644",,,,,,,,
28/06/2018,"2,390",,,,,,,,
29/06/2018,981,,,,,,,,
30/06/2018,0,,,,,,,,

For example, "Foods" would be the table name, "Date" and "Calories In" would be column names. "01/06/2018" is the Date, "0" is the "Calories in" and so on.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. There is no right or wrong answer here which renders this question as being off topic. I would probably go with the CSV given the vague explanation posted. But that might change once I dove in.

Comment: I'd almost 100% take CSV over Excel. Your CSV layout example is not clear though

Comment: When given the choice I take CSV over Excel.  The two primary reasons are 1) I don't have to install the Excel infrastructure on my server and 2) I can crack the CSV open with Notepad++.  As to "how?", you'd use a Flat File connection.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include representative sample data, __*as text*__, in your question.  Links to images are less useful than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky, I just pulled my fitbit data as this peaked my curiosity.  That csv is messy.  You basically have mixed file formats in one file.  That won't be straight forward in SSIS.  The XLS format and like you mentioned the food logs tagging each day on the worksheet, SSIS won't like that changing.

CSV:
[image]
XLS:
[image]

Couple of options off the top of my head that I see for CSV.

**Individual exports from Fitbit**

I see you can pick which data you want to include in your export:  Body, Foods, Activities, Sleep.

1. Do each export individually, saving each file with a prefix of what type of data it is.
2. Then build SSIS with multiple foreach loops and data flow task for each individual file format.

That would do it, but would be a tedious effort when having to export the data from Fitbit.

**Handle the one file with all the data**

This option you would have to get creative since the formats are mixed and you have sections with difference column definitions, etc.

One option would be to create a staging table with as many columns as which ever section has the most, which looks to be maybe "Activities".  Give each column a generic name as Column1,Column2 and make them all VARCHAR.

Since we have mixed "formats" and not all data types would line up we just need to get all the data out first and then sort out conversion later.

From there you can build one data flow and flat file source and [also get line number added](https://hansmichielscom.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/) since we will need to sort out where each section of data is later.

When building out the file connection for your source you will have to manually add all columns since the first row of data in your file doesn't include all the commas for each field, SSIS won't be able to detect all the columns.  Manually add the number of columns needed, also make sure:

- Text Qualifier = "
- Header row Delimiter = {LF}
- Row Delimiter = {LF}
- Column Delimiter = ,

That should get you data loaded into a database at least into a stage table.   From there you would need to use a bunch of T-SQL to zero in on each "section" of data and then parse, convert and load from there.

Small test I did I just had table call TestTable:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [LineNumber] [INT] NULL,
    [Column1] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column2] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column3] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column4] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column5] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column6] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column7] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column8] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Column9] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL
)
```

Dataflow and hooked up the file source:

[image]

[image]

Execute dataflow and then I had data loaded as:

[image]

From there I worked out some T-SQL to get to each "Section" of data.  Here's an example that shows how you could filter to the "Foods" section:

```
DECLARE @MaxLine INT = (
                           SELECT MAX([LineNumber])
                           FROM   [TestTable]
                       );

--Something like this, using a sub query that gets you starting and ending line numbers for each section.
--Doing the conversion of what column that section of data ended up in.
SELECT     CONVERT(DATE, [a].[Column1]) AS [Date]
         , CONVERT(BIGINT, [a].[Column2]) AS [CaloriesIn]
FROM       [TestTable] [a]
INNER JOIN (
               --Something like this to build out starting and ending line number for each section
               SELECT [Column1]
                    , [LineNumber] + 2 AS [StartLineNumber] --We add 2 here as the line that start the data in a section is 2 after its "heading"
                    , LEAD([LineNumber], 1, @MaxLine) OVER ( ORDER BY [LineNumber] )
                      - 1 AS [EndLineNumber]
               FROM   [TestTable]
               WHERE  [Column1] IN ( 'Body', 'Foods', 'Activities' ) --Each of the sections of data
           ) AS [Section]
    ON [a].[LineNumber]
       BETWEEN [Section].[StartLineNumber] AND [Section].[EndLineNumber]
WHERE      [Section].[Column1] = 'Foods'; --Then just filter on what sectoin you want.
```

Which in turn gave me the following:

[image]

There could be other options for parsing that data, but this should give a good starting point and a idea on how tricky this particular CSV file is.

As for the XLS option, that would be straight forward for all sections except food logs.  You would basically setup an excel file connection and each sheet would be a "table" in the source in the data flow and have individual data flows for each worksheet.

[image]

But then what about Food logs. Once those changed and you rolled into the next month or something SSIS would freak out, error, probably complain about metadata.

One obvious work around would be manually manipulate the excel and merge all of them into one "Food Log" sheet prior to running it through SSIS.  Not ideal because you'd probably want something completely automated.

I'd have to tinker around with that.  Maybe a script task and some C# code to combine all those sheets into one, parsing the date out of each sheet name and appending it to the data prior to a data flow loading it.  Maybe possible.

Looks like there are challenges with both of the files Fitbit is exporting out no matter which format you look at.

Comment: Thanks a lot! really well explained. I think I will begin going down the XLS route without the food logs for the timebeing as this seems like the quickest way to get something working.